# sqllite - get the total minutes worked per each timesheet

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables: *persons*, *timesheets*, and *timesheetTasks*. [Click to see the tables with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GloO.png).

I would like to get the total *Work*, *Break*, *Sick*, and *Leave* minutes per each timesheet. I was able to get the sum of the minutes but only per one timesheet (snapshot at the bottom of the image link above) with the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT t.ROWID AS timesheetId, 
       SUM(ROUND(((julianday(tt.offTime) - julianday(tt.onTime))*1440),0)) AS minsWorked 
    FROM timesheets t, timesheetTasks tt 
    WHERE t.ROWID = tt.timesheetId 
     AND (tt.taskType != "Break" AND tt.taskType != "Sick" AND tt.taskType != "Leave")),

   (SELECT SUM(ROUND(((julianday(tt.offTime) - julianday(tt.onTime))*1440),0)) AS minsBreak 
    FROM timesheets t, timesheetTasks tt 
    WHERE t.ROWID = tt.timesheetId 
     AND (tt.taskType = "Break")),

   (SELECT SUM(ROUND(((julianday(tt.offTime) - julianday(tt.onTime))*1440),0)) AS minsSick 
    FROM timesheets t, timesheetTasks tt 
    WHERE t.ROWID = tt.timesheetId 
     AND (tt.taskType = "Sick")),

   (SELECT SUM(ROUND(((julianday(tt.offTime) - julianday(tt.onTime))*1440),0)) AS minsLeave 
    FROM timesheets t, timesheetTasks tt 
    WHERE t.ROWID = tt.timesheetId 
     AND (tt.taskType = "Leave"));
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/077cb/3

How do I get total *Break*, *Sick*, *Leave*, and *Work* minutes for ALL timesheets please? The timesheets with no timesheetTasks assigned need to show 0 (or null) per each minute column. The Work minutes are taskType not equal to '*Break*', '*Sick*', and '*Leave*'.

Your help much appreciated! I've been struggling with this for almost 2 days!

Comment: Where does `ROWID` come from? Likely the reason for only employee output. Also, your sqlfiddle may be a dead link.

Comment: **ROWID** is automatically generated by SQLlite per each row

Comment: Of course, the autonumber field. Got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregates instead of multiple subqueries. And to include all existing timesheets, left join on the *timesheets* table which will return `NULL` values for non-matchs.

```
SELECT ts.ROWID As timesheetId, 

       SUM(CASE WHEN (tt.taskType != "Break" AND tt.taskType != "Sick"
                      AND tt.taskType != "Leave")
                THEN ROUND(((julianday(tt.offTime) - julianday(tt.onTime))*1440),0) 
                ELSE NULL
           END) AS minsWork,

       SUM(CASE WHEN tt.taskType = "Break"
                THEN ROUND(((julianday(tt.offTime) - julianday(tt.onTime))*1440),0)
                ELSE NULL
           END) AS minsBreak,

       SUM(CASE WHEN tt.taskType = "Sick"
                THEN ROUND(((julianday(tt.offTime) - julianday(tt.onTime))*1440),0) 
                ELSE NULL
           END) AS minsSick,

       SUM(CASE WHEN tt.taskType = "Leave"
                THEN ROUND(((julianday(tt.offTime) - julianday(tt.onTime))*1440),0) 
                ELSE NULL
           END) AS minsLeave

FROM timesheets ts 
LEFT JOIN timesheetTasks tt 
       ON ts.ROWID = tt.timesheetId
GROUP BY ts.ROWID
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/077cb/9/0)

Comment: Hi @Parfait, this returns minutes ok, but only for timesheets with timesheet tasks (0 & 1). The point is to get this result for all 4 timesheets. For timesheets with no timesheet tasks (timesheets 2 & 3) all the minute values need to be either 0 or null. The SQL fiddle link works for me ok, try this one please: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/077cb/4

Comment: See update with sqlfiddle. Simply left join on the timesheets table.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, that does exactly what I wanted!